# Google Plus One button to iPhone app

Tags: ios, google-plus, google-plus-one

I'd like to add a Google +1 button to an iOS app that takes a link as a parameter.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The recently launched Google+ API: http://developers.google.com/+/overview has Objective C support: http://developers.google.com/+/downloads

Answer (score 0):

I would research Facebook Like button in iOS, as right now the solutions for using the +1 and the Like buttons inside of an iOS app are probably similar since the same thing is being done (using a website-centric tool inside of an iOS app.)

The following link describes a way to use a webview to implement the Like button, and I don't think it would be too hard to adapt it for the +1 button.  Caveat is that there are some usability issues to overcome with the Login itself (with the FB version), although admittedly I don't know exactly how Google handles a user who isn't logged in when they click the +1.

http://angelolloqui.blogspot.com/2010/11/facebook-like-button-on-ios.html

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way of showing the Google+1 button is, first download the google+ ios sdk and then include it in your xcode project. After the previous step now drag a button on to xib file. After that try to change the custom class of the button to GPPSignInButton (You can change the custom class of the button from the right hand side property window). Then in the .h file of controller create an IBOutlet of type GPPSignInButton and then from the file's owner assign that IBOutlet to the button dragged on xib.

Now whenever you will run the application you will se google+1 button on ur xib and through this button we can perform signIn activity.

Details
https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sign-in